# How do I write to listView in Fragment from a getter?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, getter-setter

I'm trying to populate a `listview` in a `Fragment`, and the data is coming from a getter set from another `Fragment`. However, I keep overwriting the data instead of adding new when I add more items from the first `Fragment`.

I've tried finding numerous solution here on Stackoverflow, but none of them have worked for me. I'm fairly certain that it's because I instantiate a new list every time my code runs, but I can't seem to find out how I solve this.

The code below is the `Fragment` that receives the data through the `getData()` method at the bottom.

```
public class FoodFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageButton addFood;
    String foods, carbo, protein, fats;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> itemList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food, container, false);


        addFood = view.findViewById(R.id.addFood);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEaten);

        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        getInfo();

        if(foods != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i <1; i++){
                itemList.add(foods);
            }
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TrackingFragment());
                fr.addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void getInfo(){
        TrackingActivity trackingActivity = new TrackingActivity();
        foods = trackingActivity.getName();
        carbo = trackingActivity.getCarbohydrates();
        protein = trackingActivity.getProtein();
        fats = trackingActivity.getFats();

    }
}
```

Comment: Change the values on your Arraylist and just call "notifyDataSetChanged()" on your adapter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. For example if I use itemList.add(foods, i), I'll just get i amount of the same item. Then when I run the code again with another item, I'll get i amount of that item. It overwrites the item already on the list istead off adding a new one.

Comment: Lets say you use an array list
x for example.
if you make your adapter with x, you can do whatever you want with x, and whenever you call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter, it will check what values does the x variable holds and update accordingly, doesnt matter if you deleted your previous values.

Comment: Try to create your **itemList** only on the first time, i.e. change `itemList = new ArrayList<>();` to `if(itemList == null) itemList = new ArrayList<>();`. Hope that helps! Otherwise, pls clarify "when I add more items from the first Fragment", what is **first Fragment**? how to go from **first Fragment** to **this Fragment**? Also what `for(int i = 0; i <1; i++){` is used for?

Answer (score 0):

When you use and adapter you create a link between it and a collection of elements that you can change every time you want.

Every time you add an element to your itemList you are working outside the user interface scope, so you have to call a notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter to re-align the UI ListView with your itemList ArrayList.

In your case first make sure that you are obtaining the data you expected from your source in getInfo() and second you need probably to move the add of elements into the onclick listener.

Remember also that the function onCreateView is called every time there is a configuration change in your application, so in that case your itemList will be recreated continuously.

Check also the getinfo function: as far as I can see it recreate a new object from every call so you force this object to have default values.
This is not the correct way of doing the behavihour you are trying to achieve: instead of using an activity to store important data just use a simple java class that is shared by reference between fragments.

Hope this help or give you some hints.
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am optaining the info that I need to populate the listView. The onClickListener in thís class in simply a button to change to another Fragment where that info is selected by the user. I'll have a look at the notifyDataSetChanged() again. Thanks.